# SQL Column ambiguously defined error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to write a query that tells me the celebrities that have both starred in a movie and released an album:

```
Select CELEB
From StarredIn
INTERSECT
Select CELEB
From Releases;
```

Then from these celebs, I have to count the number of movies and albums for each celeb in this query. Here's how I tried doing this:

```
Select DISTINCT CELEB, COUNT(MOVIE) AS number_of_movies, COUNT(ALBUM) AS number_of_albums
From StarredIn, Releases
Where CELEB = 
(Select CELEB
From StarredIn
INTERSECT
Select CELEB
From Releases);
```

When I run this in oracle I get an error saying "Column ambiguously defined." So how can I fix that?

Here's the tables I'm using for this:

```
CREATE TABLE StarredIn (
  celeb VARCHAR(30), 
  movie VARCHAR(100)
);
CREATE TABLE Releases (
  celeb VARCHAR(30), 
  album VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below query,

```
SELECT A.CELEB, A.MOVIECOUNT, B.ALBUMCOUNT FROM
(SELECT  S.CELEB, COUNT(S.MOVIE) AS MOVIECOUNT FROM StarredIn S WHERE S.CELEB IN (SELECT  DISTINCT CELEB FROM Releases) GROUP BY S.celeb) A,
(SELECT  R.CELEB, COUNT(R.ALBUM) AS ALBUMCOUNT  FROM Releases R WHERE R.CELEB IN (SELECT  DISTINCT CELEB FROM StarredIn) GROUP BY R.celeb) B
WHERE A.CELEB = B.CELEB
```

Comment: Now I get an error saying S.ALBUM invalid identifier.

Comment: Try with R.ALBUM and S.MOVIE instead :)

Comment: It says that S.Celeb is not a single-group group function. If I change S.Celeb to just say Celeb then it goes back to saying that the where statement is ambiguously defined

Comment: Updated the answer, please check and let me know.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors now however the movie and album count is way too high. We're talking results that claim these celebs have released over 100,000 albums and starred in over 200,000 movies.

Comment: Updated the answer :) Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: The numbers are lower but they're still too high. For example it says Nicole Kidman has starred in 98 movies but the starredin table says she only starred in 28. She also only released 1album but the result also says 98. In fact for all the celebs it has the same count for albums and movies.

Comment: And again even changing R.Movie to S.Movie I still get the same problem. The count is too high and it's the exact same count for movies and albums.

Comment: Could you please update the expected output? So that it will be easier to understand the question.

Comment: The expected output is the list of all the celebs that are on both the starredin table and releases table and then I want the number of movies the celeb have starred in as well as the number of albums the celeb has released. So for example with Nicole Kidman I expect the number_of_movies to be 28 and the number_of_albums to be 1. Right now the number_of_movies is 98 and the number_of_albums is also 98.

Comment: I have modified the answer. Could you please check again?

Comment: With your updated code, the album count is now accurate but the movie count is still inaccurate. It still says Nicole Kidman starred in 98 movies when she only starred in 28. It says Gwen Stefani starred in 2 movies but she only starred in 1 and it's like that for all the celebs.

Comment: Still the same problem except now it seems the order of the celebs has been changed but that's it. The movie count is still inaccurate.

Comment: Changed it again assuming that celeb should have starred in movie as well as album. Check it. :)

Comment: Still getting the same output as before. Album count is fine but movie count is too high.

Comment: Let me explain what i have done. I am displaying the total count of movies of celebrities who have starred in albums. Similarly, I am displaying the total number of albums of celebrities who have starred in movies. If number of albums are getting displayed correctly then number of movies should also be correct. I simulated the same in my system and it is working fine.

Comment: So you tested it. Did you make sample tables to see if the movies results were correct? I'm trying to understand if it's a problem with the query or with my tables.

Comment: Ok it looks like there was a problem with my tables.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Select DISTINCT table1.ColumnName, COUNT(table2.ColumnName2) AS number_of_movies, COUNT(table1.ColumnName3) AS number_of_albums
From table1, table2
Where table1.ColumnName = ''
```

Comment: same column exist in both tables     so please use table1.column , table2.column2 etc in your query..